# Windows Forms is getting too large

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

Im making a program with many many pages... and in my design, the buttons will eventually get stacked up, so its getting harder and harder to work the more there are.

This question is a clone of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713764/windows-form-wpf-too-large-how-can-i-split-it-up).
However, i didn't really get the answer since they were talking about xaml and wpf.

I've also tried to make multiple windows forms, hide and show them to split it up.
But when i hide and show a wndow, its very very easily to see the GUI fading in and out which looks ugly.

I want an instant hide/show function so it looks like its just 1 program with 1 window and now switching.

So what are the tecniques to make a big windowsforms program more managable?

Comment: Seems you're looking for `UserControl`s. Yet, the general consensus is that winforms is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy apps. You should seriously consider looking into WPF.

Comment: Proper design is first and foremost.  Look at Visual Studio as an example of a program that has an incredibly rich user interface but can still squeeze it all in a usable single window.  Do consider hiring the help, good UI design is a profession.

Comment: One common technique is to use tab folders. Hans' example, Visual Studio is showing just about everything is is showing in this way.. But don't expect that technique alone will be enough. You will have to re-think all the workings of what you already have and be open to radical changes!

Answer (score 0):

You may create a couple of **UserControls**, organize and separate your logic on them. Then you may use **String Array** to store your control names and iterate througth items to display apropriate view. The form may have **Panel** as container and **Dock** Style defined as **Fill**. The simplefied code will look like:

```
   public class MyContainer:Control
   {
    public MyContainer(string szControlName, UserControl nControl)
    {
        UserControlName = szControlName; MyControl = nControl;
    }
       public string UserControlName { get; set; }
       public UserControl MyControl { get; set; }
   }
```

In main form:

```
    public List<MyContainer> MyNavigationArray;
    public void InitArray()
    {
        MyNavigationArray = new List<MyContainer>(MyFormPageCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < MyFormPageCount; i++)
        {

            MyNavigationArray.Add(new MyContainer(TheNameOfUserControl, new PredefinedUserControl()));
        }
    }
    private void NextButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyContainer mYcn = this.panel1.Controls[0] as  MyContainer;
        int nCurPos = MyNavigationArray.IndexOf(mYcn);
        if (nCurPos < MyNavigationArray.Count)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            MyContainer c = MyNavigationArray[nCurPos + 1];
            panel1.Controls.Add(c);
            c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
     }
```

All information stored inside user controls will be in your array and can be used later. 
Hope this helped.