# How design window for editing multiple database tables

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a database with 4 tables. The user should be able to edit, add, delete, rows from each table. The table will be shown in a datagrid. one table that contains 1000 - 2000 rows, but the others just have up to 50 rows.

Is there a "better" way of displaying 4 datagrids than using a TabControl and a tab for each table?

The users has requested that the program should look similar to Excel.

If TabControl is the way to go. Should I load the datagrids at startup or when the user selects the tab?

```
<Window
    x:Class="Foo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="611"
    Height="401"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>

            <TabControl x:Name="tcControl" >
                <TabItem Header="FooTable1">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid
                                x:Name="dataGrid1"
                                Margin="57,20,60,37"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CanUserAddRows="false"
                                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FooTable1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                                RowEditEnding="laserDataDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>

                                <!-- ... -->
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="FooTable2">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid
                                x:Name="dataGrid2"
                                Margin="57,20,60,37"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CanUserAddRows="false"
                                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FooTable2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                                RowEditEnding="laserDataDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>

                                <!-- ... -->
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="FooTable3">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid
                                x:Name="dataGrid3"
                                Margin="57,20,60,37"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CanUserAddRows="false"
                                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FooTable3, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                                RowEditEnding="laserDataDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>

                                <!-- ... -->
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="FooTable4">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid
                                x:Name="dataGrid4"
                                Margin="57,20,60,37"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CanUserAddRows="false"
                                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FooTable4, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                                RowEditEnding="laserDataDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>

                                <!-- ... -->
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Either way it will work. You are asking for opinions (typically it's the same as "what is the **best** way to ..." question). Can you describe the *problem*? E.g. "it's slow". Maybe you are asking for [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (to add abstractions, etc.). *"should look similar to Excel"* - do you stuck with layout?

Comment: My problem is that I find it kind of "messy" to handle four datagrids in one tabcontrol. The xaml file get a bit long > 500 lines. But I will ask in Code Review. Thank you!

Comment: See [how to handle large xaml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907321(v=vs.110).aspx) and (seems the same as yours) `TabControl` [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3713764/1997232).

Comment: UserControls will make it less messy. Thanks!